# How to change desktop-first design code to mobile-first with tailwind css (responsiveness)

Tags: html, responsive-design, tailwind-css, media-queries

I developed a website with Html and tailwind css, now I need to make the website responsive. I just discovered that tailwind uses a mobile-first breakpoint system, meanwhile I developed mine using the desktop-first approach.
Now I am confused on how to change the design into a mobile design using tailwind css, so that I can make the website responsive.

I tried changing the available styles to fit into a mobile screen size but it isn't working, rather it was scattering the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Tailwind uses a mobile-first approach by default. These are the breakpoints defined by default in Tailwind:

```js
screens: {
  'sm': '640px', // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }
  'md': '768px', // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }
  'lg': '1024px', // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }
  'xl': '1280px', // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
  '2xl': '1536px', // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
}
```

If you give, for instance, these classes to an element `"m-0 md:m-4"`, the element will have a margin only when screen width is larger than 768px. You are setting the general rule for smaller screens and a specific rule for larger screens (that's why it's considered mobile-first).

You can change to a desktop-first behaviour by overriding the `screens` configuration in a slightly different way. Add the following to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  /* ... other config... */
  theme: {
    /* ... other theme rules ... */
    screens: {
      '2xl': {'max': '1535px'}, // => @media (max-width: 1535px) { ... }
      'xl': {'max': '1279px'}, // => @media (max-width: 1279px) { ... }
      'lg': {'max': '1023px'}, // => @media (max-width: 1023px) { ... }
      'md': {'max': '767px'}, // => @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
      'sm': {'max': '639px'}, // => @media (max-width: 639px) { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

**Important:** `max-width` breakpoints must be listed in descending order so that they override each other as expected. (see docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#max-width-breakpoints))

Note we are using max widths now instead of min widths. Now, an element with class `"m-0 md:m-4"` will only have a margin if screen width in **under** 767px.

If you already styled your site for larger screens, I suggest you add the above configuration to your `tailwind.config.js` (you can add/remove/edit breakpoints as you wish) and start using modifiers (such as `md:`) for the specific styles you want to apply to smaller screens only.